# How do I order countries by name in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with the following task from the platform Codesignal:

After some investigation, you've created a database containing a foreignCompetitors table, which has the following structure:

`competitor`: the name of the competitor;
`country`: the country in which the competitor is operating.
In your report, you need to include the `number of competitors per country` and an additional row at the bottom that contains a summary: `("Total:", total_number_of_competitors)`

Given the foreignCompetitors table, compose the resulting table with two columns: `country and competitors`. The first column should contain the `country name`, and the second column should contain the `number of competitors in this country`. The table should be `sorted by the country names` in ascending order. In addition, it should have an extra row at the bottom with the summary, as described above.

Example

For the following table foreignCompetitors

[image]

[image]

my solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE solution()
BEGIN
    (SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS competitors 
    FROM foreignCompetitors
    GROUP BY country
    ORDER BY country)

    UNION
    
    SELECT 'Total:', COUNT(*) FROM foreignCompetitors;
    
END
```

But my output is:

[image]

The result of the countries is not sorted by their names.
I cannot understand why is that even though I try to sort them with ORDER BY.

Comment: Any sorting done by your `ORDER BY` clause is completely irrelevant since it's the *input* to a subsequent `UNION` which offers no ordering guarantees. The only `ORDER BY` that guarantees output order is one applied to the *complete* query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(country, 'Total:') AS country, COUNT(*) AS competitors
FROM foreignCompetitors
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY country;
```

If you want to stick with your union approach, then you need to introduce a computed column into the union query which places the total row at the bottom of the result set.  Consider:

```sql
SELECT country, competitors
FROM
(
    SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS competitors, 1 AS pos
    FROM foreignCompetitors
    GROUP BY country
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'Total:', COUNT(*), 2
    FROM foreignCompetitors
) t
ORDER BY pos, country;
```

Comment: Thank you, but why my solution is not working

Comment: @vanderwaal You need to do a bit more work to make that approach work, q.v. my updated answer.  But if rollup works for you, then use it, at it simplifies the query.